# How can I calculate sum of column value in linq to sql query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm write this query:

```
var query2 = (from p in behzad.Compare_closed_numbers_in_CRM_and_Billing_system_detail_counters
               where p.fileid == point.id
               select new
               {
                   p.count
               }).ToArray();
```

in count column have any value,and I want to sum all of the count value. For example:
[image]

how can I implant that?thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If count field is int try this:

```
int sum = behzad.Compare_closed_numbers_in_CRM_and_Billing_system_detail_counters
     .Where(t=>t.fileid == point.id)
     .Select(t => t.Count ?? 0).Sum();
```

If count field is `nvarchar(max)` try this:

```
int sum = behzad.Compare_closed_numbers_in_CRM_and_Billing_system_detail_counters
         .Where(t=>t.fileid == point.id)
         .Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Count)).Sum();
```

Comment: Oh yes ,thanks for pay attention to my problem and answer.it's work

Comment: There is no need to have select right before sum. Sum has an override with the same meaning so just move the func to a parameter to sum.